# Rotating an image around a reference point

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d, image-rotation

I'm trying to rotate the image around a reference point in Java using BufferedImage and AffineTransform, at first it seemed exactly what I needed, but it turns out it doesn't behave as expected. I need to do some rudimentary rotations, in multiples of 90, so I tried to do `getQuadrantRotateInstance`, but, if the reference point is at 0,0 then I get a RasterFormatException: `Transformed height (0) is less than or equal to 0.`

```
var rotation = switch (transform) {
    case TRANS_NONE -> 0;
    case TRANS_ROT90 -> 1;
    case TRANS_ROT180 -> 2;
    case TRANS_ROT270 -> 3;
    default -> throw new NotImplementedException();
};
var transform = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(rotation, referenceX, referenceY);
var operation = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
var rotated = operation.filter(source, null);
```

By the looks of it the image gets rotated out of the canvas (into negative coordinates), resulting in exception above.

What would be the proper solution to create a rotated variant of the image *without* cropping or rotating around a center point like existing solutions do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating an image by an angle around the center point:

```java
private BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage buffImage, double angle) {
    double radian = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radian));
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radian));

    int width = buffImage.getWidth();
    int height = buffImage.getHeight();

    int nWidth = (int) Math.floor((double) width * cos + (double) height * sin);
    int nHeight = (int) Math.floor((double) height * cos + (double) width * sin);

    BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D graphics = rotatedImage.createGraphics();

    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    graphics.translate((nWidth - width) / 2, (nHeight - height) / 2);
    // This is the rotation around the center point - change this line
    graphics.rotate(radian, (double) (width / 2), (double) (height / 2));
    graphics.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, null);
    graphics.dispose();

    return rotatedImage;
}
```

To change the origin point of the rotation see `javadoc` of the method [rotate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate(double,%20double,%20double)).

---

Source: [Creating simple captcha](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810191959/https://drakonoved.org/blog/2017/11/07/creating-simple-captcha.html).